# nginx - insecure http server is redirecting wrongly to an https server

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I've got a small website that I'm running on docker, with the 'dev' version on port 9090 and the 'master' version running on port 8080.

I'm using Nginx on the host (not running on docker) to handle the proxying on port 80/443 for requests coming from the internet.

The  port 80/443 proxying works perfectly. No problems there.

**Problem:** When try and create a server running on port 90 (to show the dev version of the site) which is intended to be insecure, this seems to attempt a redirect back to the SSL version of the site, which is confirmed by the browser redirecting to SSL, and i get an error on the page : ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

If i comment out the server running on port 80, this problem goes away, but then i lose my port 80 redirects on the live/master site.

Can anyone see what might be the problem in how i'm setting up the config - thanks! Config below :

```
server {
listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk;
    {some ssl config here}
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 90;
server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused probably by *Strict-Transport-Security* header set on port 433. Which told browser to force SSL on this server/domain for the time in header.

Try to remove header and try on cache free browser.